# Named route with a parameter format

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have researched and have not been able to find an example of how to do this properly.

I need to combine the following:

```
Route::get('self', ['as' => 'self', 'uses' => 'FrontendController@self']);

Route::get('self/{type}', function($type = 'type'){});
```

Comment: why you need to combine that?

Comment: I want to use a named controller and have a parameter as well.

Comment: `Route::get('self/{type?}', ['as' =>  'uses' => 'FrontendController@self']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your route like this

```
Route::get('self/{type?}', ['as' => 'uses' => 'FrontendController@self']);
```

And in your controller method you can use the parameter

```
public function self($type = null)
{
// your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use group prefixing to solve it. For example :

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'self'], function()
{
    Route::get('/','FrontendController@self');
    Route::get('{type}',function($type){
        return $type;
    });
});
```